Spring boot IBM MQ not sending message to topic
My requirement is to send a message to a topic instead of a queue using IBM MQ. I am doing below configuration to send message using JmsTemplate.
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MQConfiguration {

    @Value("${notification.topic.name}")
    String notificationTopicName;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "jms-mq.notification")
    public MQConfigurationProperties mqConfigurationProperties() {
        return new MQConfigurationProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory() {
        MQConnectionFactoryFactory mqConnectionFactoryFactory = new MQConnectionFactoryFactory(mqConfigurationProperties(), null);
        MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = mqConnectionFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory(MQQueueConnectionFactory.class);
       // mqQueueConnectionFactory.se
       return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerContainerFactory(DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer){
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory=new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        configurer.configure(defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory,mqQueueConnectionFactory());
        defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setClientId("producer");
        return defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate=new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(notificationTopicName);
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory());
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

application.yaml

jms-mq:
  notification:
    conn-name: edb2pre2.momentum.co.za(1414)
    queueManager: edb2pre1.que.mgr
    channel: TCP.CLT.CHL

Below is the code to send message to topic
 try {
            String jsonMessage= objectMapper.writeValueAsString(notification);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(notificationTopicName,jsonMessage);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException | JmsException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

But everytime I am receiving an error
com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC1112: The operation for a domain specific object was not valid. The operation 'createTopic' is not valid for type 'QueueSession'.
A JMS application attempted to perform an operation on domain specific object, but the operation is valid only for the other messaging domain.
Update: As suggested by @JoshMc instead of using queue connection factory using mq connection factory resolved the issue.
 MQConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = mqConnectionFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.class);


Try a connection factory instead of a queue connection factory.

@JoshMc thank you its working. I am putting an update to the answe

You can post a self answer and then accept it, this is the right process

Instead of using MQQueueConnectionFactory MQConnectionFactory resolves the issue.
MQConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = mqConnectionFactoryFactory.createConnectionFactory(MQConnectionFactory.class);

